# Office 365 user cannot be deleted

Tags: microsoft-office-365, entra-id

I have a office 365 user, says its synced with AD object.
The AD object has been deleted long time ago and now i'm stuck with the Office 365 object and the delete option is grayed out.
Any ideas how to get rid of old users no longer exist in AD?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Azure AD Connect? What's the state of synchronization health? When's the last time a sync was run?

Comment: I use dirsync to sync AD users to Office 365. I had once a user which was deleted long time ago, and now no longer in AD however i still see it in Office 365. i need to get rid of the Office 365 user, can't seem to delete it.

Comment: Make sure you synchronization status is OK in DirSync. As soon as your synchronization is fixed, the user will be deleted from Azure. You might want to upgrade to AD Connect, since DirSync is deprecated. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-dirsync-deprecated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer to the issue discussed in this thread is by using powershell, run the command : Remove-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "davidchew@contoso.com" -Force

This deletes the Office 365 object, if not linked to any AD user.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If I were you, I'd try with a DirSync/Azure AD Connect "initial".

On the host running DirSync/Azure AD Connect, start PowerShell then execute:

```
import-module adsync
Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType 'Initial'
```

This will fully refresh the metaverse DB (in a standard scheduled action only the "delta" is refreshed).